# How to switch the condition between two cases in data-bind

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, data-binding

I have an ordered list and I want to set the condition so that the list item inside can be sortable or not.

If the condition `$root.userPermissionsList().write()` is true, then the ordered list will be sortable:

```
<ol class="timeline Question" 
    data-bind=" sortable: {data: questions, afterAdd: $root.focusQuestion}">
```

In contrast, if

`!($root.userPermissionsList().write())`

then the ordered list will not be sortable:

```
<ol class="timeline Question" data-bind=" foreach: {data: questions}">
```

I tried to combine the condition like this:

```
<ol class="timeline Question" 
    data-bind="visible:$root.userPermissionsList().write(), sortable: {data: questions, afterAdd: $root.focusQuestion}">
<ol class="timeline Question"
    data-bind="visible:!($root.userPermissionsList().write()), foreach: {data: questions}">
```

but it seems not to work. Does anybody have an idea how to switch between these two cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout's `visible` binding uses the css property setting `display: none` to hide elements. Your solution would therefore produce HTML similar to:

```
<ol style="display: none;">
  <ol>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

This isn't valid markup. You could use knockout's `if` binding to make sure only one ordered list is added to the DOM tree.

```
<!-- ko if: $root.userPermissionsList().write() -->
<ol class="timeline Question" data-bind="sortable: {data: questions, afterAdd: $root.focusQuestion}">
  <li> ... </li>
</ol>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: $root.userPermissionsList().write() -->
<ol class="timeline Question" data-bind="foreach: questions">
  <li> ... </li>
</ol>
<!-- /ko -->
```

If `write` is an observable, knockout will remove and add a list element to the DOM every time it updates (which might be slow).

If it isn't observable, its value has to be set correctly before the `<ol>` is data bound.

The virtual element bindings aren't very pretty. You could also define two templates (one using sortable, one plain foreach) and pick one of the templates based on the value of `write`. But let's not get too far off topic...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! May I ask that is it the comment like <!-- ko if: $root.userPermissionsList().write() --> affect to the code or not? I am new in data-binding topic so maybe this could be such stupid question :D

Comment: Good question. Normally, your `if` data-bind will look like this: `<div data-bind="if: condition"> content </div>`. This will _always_ render a `<div>`, and render content _only_ if the condition variable is true.

The only difference between this `if` binding, and the comment-like `if` binding, is that the second one does not create an empty `<div>`.